# Why does java type erasure change the non-generic type of target collection?

Tags: java, type-erasure

First of all, I'm coming from C# but I'm aware of type erasuring in java.
But I don't understand the following code-example...

When I define a target collection with a concrete type, I expect that collection to retain that type. Even if the actual collection is the result of a generic method.
So I expect a ClassCastException if an inappropriate collection is assigned. But no exception occurs, but the inner type of the target collection changes at runtime ...
I later iterate on the collection, I get during the iteration ClassCastExceptions ...
Am I doing something wrong? Or is this strange behavior correct?

```
//There are 2 classes. Both implementing the same interface.
class CA implements IA
class CB implements IA



public void method1()
{
    //This is the target-collection. The Type is set to CA(!)
    //In Java, I expect an exception here! Why does Java change the type of
    //collection? This is very dangerous ... because I have defined a 
    //specific type. So I expect to get what I have defined.
    Collection<CA> result = getInstances();

    //Some Code...

    //Time to iterate the instances
    for(CA instance : result)
    {
        //ClassCastException at second instance...
    }
}

public <T extends IA> Collection<T> getInstances()
{
    //Resulting collection
    Collection<T> instances = new LinkedList<T>();


    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        //In C#, an exception would occure exactly here.
        //That would be sooo fine... :(
        //I already wrote a solution for this. I use Class<T> to cast at
        //this point. So thats not my question. I just want to understand
        //why java is allowing to change the inner type of collection
        T instance = (T)getInstance(i);

        //Add the instance
        instances.add(instance);
    }

    //At this point, the collection will containing CA and(!) CB instances...
    return instances;
}

//Non-generic method!
public IA getInstance(int i)
{
    if(i == 0)
         return new CA();
    else
         return new CB();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I define a target collection with a concrete type, I expect that collection to retain that type

Wrong expectation. Generics in Java are (almost) relevant "compile-time only".

There is only one ArrayList class, and that works with arguments of type `Object`. The errors you get from the compiler when adding "the wrong type", are as said: compile time only.

Of course, you could create your **own** list implementation, that gets instantiated with a concrete `Class` instance, and then do the corresponding checking at runtime. And *update*: you can use one of the helper methods of the Collection class, like [checkedCollection()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Class-) to create a collection/list/set/... that does exactly that.

Beyond that:

```
for(CA instance : result)
{
    //ClassCastException at second instance...
```

Here you have an explicit cast, you claim: all objects in the result list will be `CA` objects, but obviously, not all are.

Comment: There is also `Collections.checkedCollection(Collection<E>,Class<E>)`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn One never stops learning. Thanks for that hint, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: `Collections.checkedList` is a nice way to get the resulting collection type-safe. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarcoDöbert You are welcome. And feel free to accept one of the answers then ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat
I know what you mean, but i explicitly defined `Collection<CA> result = getInstances();`. Everything that happens here, I understand. Only the assignment to "Collection <CA> result" I find disturbing. From the next line, java "lies" to me. The collection is no longer of type CA, although only a collection of type CA is expected at this point. So I explicitly defined the variable.
As I said, disturbing.

Comment: @MarcoDöbert I was going to enhance my answer, but I think the other answer by kayaman nicely explains that one missing part.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing an unchecked cast at

```
T instance = (T)getInstance(i);
```

If you leave out the cast, you get a compile-time error. If you add the cast, you get a warning, but its assumed that you know what you're doing.

In this case you "don't know what you're doing", i.e. by doing an unchecked cast you're saying "To heck with the type system!". Then all bets are off, and it can't be verified at compile time that you're doing correct things. At runtime you may then get exceptions.

GhostCat mentioned about type checked collections. You don't need to implement your own classes for them, as `Collections` utility class contains methods for creating checked collections `checkedList`, `checkedSet` etc. They contain the additional `Class` argument that's used to check that the contents are of the right type. Using those would give you a runtime exception earlier, when putting elements inside the collection instead of when retrieving them.

Comment: `Collections.checkedList` is a nice way to get the resulting collection type-safe. Thanks a lot!
The unchecked cast will not produce an exception, because the generic type is implementing `IA`. So, at this point, "I know what I'm doing".
But on the other side, it was wrong. The right way to do is: `Class<T>.cast(getInstance(i));`

Comment: @MarcoDöbert no the unchecked cast comes from you putting a subtype of `IA` into a `Collection<T extends TA>`. Since `Collection<CA>` fits that type parameter, the unchecked cast is required to allow a potential `CB` from your `getInstance()` to be put into the collection. Without a cast, the compiler will prevent you from doing it, but with a cast it'll allow it even **if** it may cause a `ClassCastException` during runtime. It doesn't necessarily cause one, but the type system can't guarantee it. Using `Class.cast` is no different, unless you have the right `Class` object at hand.

Comment: Absolutely! My expectation is based on my experience in C#. In C# the generic type is not lost. Therefore, `T instance = (T) getInstance (i);` at runtime in `CA instance = (CA) getInstance (i);` translated.
In Java, the generic type is lost.
Thanks, I understand this aspect a little better now.

In my solution, I use, to be precise:
`public <T extends IA> Collection <T> getInstances (Class <T> classType)
{
     // ...
     T instance = classType.cast (getInstance (i));
}`
This gives me an exception at the expected location.